# Inserting csv in postgresql with \copy from php

Tags: php, postgresql, csv, copy

I am trying to insert csv file in postgresql database table from php script.

While using command `\copy` in `psql`:

```
\copy tablename(col1, col2, col3) FROM 'path/to/the/file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER;
```

I don't occur any problem, but while executing same command as query from php I get: Query failed: ERROR: syntax error at or near "\" LINE 1: \copy ...:

```
   $query = "\copy tablename(col1, col2, col3) FROM 'path/to/the/file.csv' DELIMITERS ',' CSV HEADER";
    $result = pg_query($conn, $query);
    if (!$result) {
      echo "An error occurred.\n";
      exit;
    }
```

From [PostgreSQL docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-copy.html) I read this

> Do not confuse COPY with the psql instruction \copy. \copy invokes
>   COPY FROM STDIN or COPY TO STDOUT, and then fetches/stores the data in
>   a file accessible to the psql client. Thus, file accessibility and
>   access rights depend on the client rather than the server when \copy
>   is used.

Maybe if someone can explain this to me, I would understand it better.

I am not a superuser so I understand that I cannot use COPY, however I assumed if I can start \copy from psgl that I can use it as query in PHP also.

EDIT

Example of my CSV

```
   date,code,name,aut,data,lat,long
    2017-06-08,431, one ,0, 11.1, 22.121,43.220
    2017-06-08,321, two,1, 13.5,32.323,23.232
    2017-06-08,210, three ,1, 19.5,23.432,43.232
```

TABLE

```
CREATE TABLE table (
gid serial NOT NULL,
date timestamptz NOT NULL,
code bigint NOT NULL,
name character varying(50),
type boolean NOT NULL,
data smallint NOT NULL,
lat numeric(12,8),
long numeric(12,8),
the_geom geometry,
CONSTRAINT table_pkey PRIMARY KEY (gid)
);
```

PHP regarding Laurenz Albe answer:

```
$path = "path/to/the/file.csv";

$csv2array = array();
if (!$fp=fopen($path,"r")) echo "The file could not be opened.<br/>";  
while (( $data = fgetcsv ($fp)) !== FALSE ){
    $data = str_replace(' ', '', $data);
    $data = implode(" ",$data);
    $csv2array[] = $data;
}
print_r($csv2array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2017-06-08 431 one 0 11.1 22.121 43.220
    [1] => 2017-06-08 321 two 1 13.5 32.323 23.232
    [2] => 2017-06-08 210 three 1 19.5 23.432 43.232
)
```

Answer (score 2):

`\copy` is not an SQL command and cannot be used with PHP.

You could read the lines into an array and use [`pg_copy_from()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-copy-from.php) to use `COPY ... FROM STDIN` with PHP.

For that, you'd have to read the data from the file into an array first.

Comment: Can you please elaborate this little bit more! I edited my question. With this code I get warning: pg_copy_from(): Copy command failed: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "date,code,name,aut,data,lat,long"
CONTEXT:  COPY sinop, line 1, column gid: "date,code,name,aut,data,lat,long" in path/to/th/file.php on line 23

Comment: How can I use COPY ... FROM STDIN?

Comment: You have to read the file and write its contents to `$csv2array`. Each line of the file should become an element of the array. I know that's not convenient, but this seems to be the only way to use `COPY` from PHP.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean. What to do after I had put all rows from csv in array (I edited my  question)? I cannot find many examples with pg_copy_from and I also dont know where and how to use COPY with PHP. I like "words" and I appriciate instructions but can I please have some example of a code?

Comment: Alright, I think I got what you instructioned me to do. Still stuck with next step.

Comment: Something is not right. Warning from the above - first line is trying to be placed in in column gid which is an integer?

Comment: That looks fine, just use delimiter `' '` (a single space) in `pg_copy_from`, since your data seem to be separated by blanks.